# Referencing a single li

Tags: meteor

I have a li list of contacts. Each li contains 2 divs on for all the contact details and another for buttons to contact/edit/delete the contact. My issue is I want to be able to edit an single individual contact by clicking its relevant edit button. As it is designed for mobile I do not want to open another modal window or add another template to the li so I want to set the html contenteditable attribute to true. However I can't find a way to do this to just the 1 contact, basically all contacts become editable which is what I do not want. I have tried various jQuery selectors/traversal methods and using 'this' but have not got the behaviour I am looking for. Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some code to show us what you've already tried.

Comment: Show some html and that will make it easier to point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery then the solution will come with the parent selector.

When you catch the event on the button, you just have to look at the parent li. Then, you can find all the children to transform them to inputs.

This code does not work. Edit is necessary

```
Template.toto.events ({
    "click .edit" : function(e){
        var par = $(event.target).parent("li");
        par.children("p").... // find children to make them editable
    }
});
```

This should lead you to your solution